# Unable to replace the hour in datetime using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Unable to replace the hour part in date-time. The change is reflecting in both hour & year. Please help in rectifying the code.

```
DECLARE @p varchar(100) = CONVERT(varchar(100), GETDATE(), 21) 

SET @p = REPLACE(@p, SUBSTRING(@p, 12, 2), '11')
PRINT @p
```

- Expected output = 2021-02-13 11:35:32.337
- Actual output   = 1121-02-13 11:39:11.347

```
DECLARE @q varchar(100) 
SET @q = REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(100), GETDATE(), 121), SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(100), GETDATE(), 121), 12, 2), 22)
PRINT @q
```

- Expected output = 2021-02-13 22:35:32.337
- Actual output   = 2221-02-13 22:38:13.223

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`REPLACE(@p, SUBSTRING(@p, 12, 2), '11')` will replace all occurrences of `SUBSTRING(@p, 12, 2)` in `@p` by `'11'`.

It happens that `SUBSTRING(@p, 12, 2)` returns `'20'` (or it could be any other value for the hour), so all occurrences of `'20'` in `@p` are replaced by `'11'`.
This is why for the year `2021` you get `1121`.

Instead of `REPLACE()` use string concatenation:

```
set @p = SUBSTRING(@p,1,11) + '11' + SUBSTRING(@p,14,LEN(@p))
```

or the function [`STUFF()`:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
set @p = STUFF(@p,12,2,'11')
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=91c69af33ab31cae8246d9a166b17582).

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit cumbersome, but `datetimefromparts()` directly does what you want:

```
select datetimefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), day(getdate()),
                         11,
                         datepart(minute, getdate()),
                         datepart(second, getdate()),
                         datepart(millisecond, getdate())
                        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to subtract the number of hours you already have, and add 11:

```
SELECT DATEADD(hour, 11,
    DATEADD(hour, -DATEPART(hour, GETDATE()), GETDATE())
);
```